# How do I run an installed terminal command in java?

Tags: java, terminal, processbuilder

I was recently writing a program that used ProcessBuilder to run terminal commands but whenever I run the program I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "convert": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
    at Downloader.uncompressImage(Downloader.java:37)
    at Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:319)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:250)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
    ... 3 more
```

I am pretty sure that this error is because it cannot find where the "convert" command is located because that is a command used by ImageMagick which I have installed on my computer. I know the command works because if I type in the command in the regular terminal window it works.

If the case is that the location for the "convert" command needs to be specified I still do not know where it is so if whoever answers this question could also tell me how to find that, that would be amazing.

In summary, I am pretty sure that the convert command is the one causing the error because it is a third party command, so my question is, how do I use the convert command without getting the error message, and if the solution requires me to find the directory of the convert command how do I do that?

If anyone wanted to see the code that is causing the error it is this:

```
public void uncompressImage (String name, boolean back, String path) {

        String b = "";  

        name = name.toLowerCase().replace("-", "").replace(" ", "").replace(".", "");

        if (back) {

            b = "-back";

        }

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

        String[] args = new String[] {"convert" , name + b + ".gif", "-coalesce", name + b + ".gif"};

        try {
            pb.command("cd " + path);
            pb.command(args);
            Process process = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

(This code is running on MacOS)

Edit: I have already tried checking `path` and `name` and both of those are correct.

Comment: This is on MacOS and I do not know what type of file convert is

Comment: Try and run it through the shell, e.g. `sh convert ...`

Comment: Shouldn't the command be `magick convert ...`  rather than just `convert ...` ?

Comment: No, the command is just "convert" but I fixed it now, the answer is right below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ProcessBuilder.directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) instead of `cd`. Add [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) to see what is going on. And remember to [`waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) your `Process` to complete. Like,

```
try {
    pb.inheritIO();
    pb.directory(new File(path));
    pb.command(args);
    Process process = pb.start();
    process.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You may also need to change `"convert"` to `"/usr/local/bin/convert"` (depending on how and where you have it installed).

Comment: I was using ```.directory``` before but I still got the same error which is why I tried cd. I also tried what you have there and I now get this error: ```java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "convert" (in directory "/Users/nathaniel/Downloads/SpritesFront"): error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
 at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
 at Downloader.uncompressImage(Downloader.java:36)
 at Main.main(Main.java:51)
```

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer (after the code), and change `"convert"` to `"/usr/local/bin/convert"` (or `"/usr/bin/convert"` or wherever you have `convert` installed).  I observe that now you get a much more reasonable error.